# Possible to add deprecation warning on install that the PHP version requirement is changing soon?

Tags: composer-php

I maintain a package that currently still has a require of php >= 5.6 and I'm planning to drop php5 support and require >=7 in a version in the near future. Is there something I can do with my composer.json so that when users install or update this package, they will see a deprecation warning, indicating that PHP5 support is being dropped in the near future? It would be particularly nice to only have this warning fire when people are installing on php5, but if that's not possible I'd still like to be able to have it warn on any installs to make sure it's put out there. I know some users of the package have had an expectation of php5 support even until fairly recently so I want to give all the fair warning I can to spur them to upgrade or at least be able to say I did all I could to warn them in advance.

Comment: Please share more details - do you want to throw such a warning during the installation, or when using your project's code?

Comment: I meant to make it more clear that I was specifically asking a composer-related question, but I admit it's a big vague in retrospect. Specifically I was hoping to have composer itself report the message during an install/update. Sometimes when I run composer in a project, composer itself will raise some notices to me triggered by the required dependencies in the project. I was hoping to replicate that, rather than log notices during usage of the code, but it looks like only the latter will be doable in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like https://github.com/symfony/deprecation-contracts, which is a wrapper around `@trigger_error` to trigger a deprecation warning.

The best place to trigger the warning would be in your lib entrypoint, which is executed every time your lib is used.

A simple PHP version check can make sure to display the warning only on PHP 5:

```
if (PHP_MAJOR_VERSION === 5) {
    trigger_deprecation('vendor/lib', '2.0', 'PHP version will be bumped to PHP 7');
}
```